# Conditional Page breaks at group level in SSRS2008 R2 reports

Tags: ssrs-2008, page-break

I have a report in SSRS 2008 R2.  This report consists of one table containing several grouping levels.  If the customer requests to see all the detail them I want a page break at the second grouping level of the table.  If only the summary details are requested then I do not want the page break as that will cause unnecessary paging.  How can I conditionally control the page break at the group level in a table?

The summary details are calculated and returned differently from the sql so I do not want to hide rows, just turn page break on or off.

Answer (score 34):

You can use expression based page breaks, which, depending on your exact table setup, might be useful.

Basically, you set up a parameter to control whether page breaks are applied.

At the **Group** level, there are **Page Break** options - set the **Page Break** property to what you require, then set the **Disabled** property to be expression based, something like:

```
=IIf(Parameters!Break.Value, false, true)
```

[image]
[image]

This means the **Page Break** will only be applied of the *Break* parameter is set to *true*.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find an answer helpful, please consider upvoting and/or setting as the accepted answer.

Comment: You're the man. This worked flawlessly for me as well. `/* ACCEPT THIS ANSWER OP */`