# Parameterized Page Breaks in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

On my frontend, I have an option to have page break for a certain group. I can change that option manually with this setting in in the "Group Property" dialog box:

[image]

When I check the "Between each instance of a group" the page break worked out but how can I parameterized this condition? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using SSRS 2008R2 or above?

Comment: Report Builder 2.0 with Server @ 2008R2.

Comment: With 2008R2 you can use Conditional Page Breaks - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513313/conditional-page-breaks-at-group-level-in-ssrs2008-r2-reports/ However, you may need to be using Report Builder 3.0 to make sure that functionality is exposed in the designer; 2.0 most likely won't have this option.