# SSRS 2008R2 optional page breaks for tablix that has 5 row groups on the tablix

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to use an existing page break parameter in a new tablix that I added to an exisitng ssrs 2008 r2 report.
I am trying the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513313/conditional-page-breaks-at-group-level-in-ssrs2008-r2-reports/ so I can use the disabled property of the page break option on on the new tablix by using a parameter value that is 'text' and the parameter values are either `True` or `False`.

The new tablix that I am using has 5 level of row groups.

[image]The problem is I do not see a 'group' property where I can set the control group name.

When I do set  the pagebreak of the tablix I am working with to the following, `=IIF(Parameters!PageBreak.Value="True",false,true)`, and run the page break parameter to true, I do get the page breaks. However when I set the page break parameter to false, all I see is information for one control group. I am basically missing all the informatiuon I need.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the horzontal bars under the `Row Groups`. If you click for example on `[StudentFullName` your property pane on the right side changes to the group properties (Properties: Tablix Member). There you navigate to **Group > Group > PageBreak > Disabled**. Now put your expression in the `Disabled` property. Just follow the steps from the other post and you are done.

**UPDATE**

If you want a page break before each new item of a group right click on your group properties (in your case for example right click on `[StudentFullName`) then go to the tab page breaks and check the `Between each instance of a group` box.

Comment: I did get to the page break logic under the group that I wanted to. However the page break logic is not working. The page break occurs all the time if I set the page break parameter to yes or no. Thus do you have any suggestions on what I can try next to solve my problem?

Comment: That depends where you want your page break. If you want a page break before each new group item, check my updated answer. If you want a page break based on another condition you have to write these true condition in the first argument of the `IIF()` statement. This way the expression evaluates true based on your condition and then the page break happens. Here is an example: `=IIf(Fields!StudentName.Value = "Peter", false, true)`

Comment: I want to place the page break on the second of the 5 control breaks on my initial placement of this question. Will you tell me and/or show me where the condition will actually be placed? I am assuming the iif statement will not be contained in the group property where the page break logic can be placed,correct? Would you show me where to place the iif statement?